# Counting how many instances of date in csv file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a CSV file with dates populated in each cell and I am wanting to count how many of each date there are and then I will be plotting onto a bar graph using matplotlib.

I'm not sure how to go about counting how many instances of each date there are?

I have the following code to read csv file but not sure where to go from here

```
def Readtoarray():
    with open('Book1.csv','r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in reader:
            XXXXXXXXX
```

Example data:

```
23/03/2020,6630997
23/03/2020,6630990
20/03/2020,6630390
20/03/2020,6630386
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Counter dict object (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
def Readtoarray():
    c = collections.Counter()
    with open('Book1.csv','r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in reader:
            c[row[0]] += 1 # or whatever the row index is for the date(s)
    return c
```

Which results in the following output:

```
>>> for k,v in c.items():
        print(k, ": ", v)

2-Sep :  4
3-Sep :  2
23-Sep :  2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way would be reading the csv file as a Pandas DataFrame and then using the `value_counts()` function

[Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

```py
import pandas as pd
 
def Readtoarray():
   
   df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
   x = df["Dates"].value_counts() # assuming the column is called Dates
```

Comment: Thanks I have added example data to original post.

I'm not sure how I go about saving the dates (There is a years worth of dates in here) into variables so I can then call them into my plot graph.

Comment: Have you tried `df["Dates"].value_counts().plot()` ?

Comment: Maybe it'd also be helpful to have a look at this other [thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022227/sorted-bar-charts-with-pandas-matplotlib-or-seaborn)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of you CSV dates?
To count the occurrences of something in Python, the best way is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```py
import collections

strings = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "a", "a", "b"]
count = collections.Counter(strings)

count.items() == {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 1}
```

**Edit**

With the date as first value in a row, assuming you don't need to do something special with these dates implying to parse them:

```py
import collections

count = collections.Counter([row[0] for row in reader])
```

It will return a dict with dates (as strings, for instance `"23/03/2020"`) as keys, and their number of occurrences as values. If you want dates as `datetime.date` objects, you can parse them in the comprehension list:

```py
import collections
import datetime

dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%d/%m/%Y") for row in reader]
count = collections.Counter(dates)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. I'll edit orignal post with example data

Comment: Okay! I just editer my answer (I hope I didn't misunderstand). :)